# Runkeeper Login

Tags: ios, swift

I am using runkeeper in my app to get connected it to the and fetch data from the same. On click of a button it directs me to the browser where I login on the web app of runkeeper, hit service after fetching access token and user_Id and return back to my aplication. Now again if I click on the button in my app to get conected, it directly asks me to redirect back to my app, but what I want is that each time I click to connect, it should ask for login. I know that I have to clear to cache and cookies, but don’t know how.

```
@IBAction func btnRunKeeperClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
   MSYRunKeeper.shareInstance.loginWithRunKeeper { (result, success) in
    print(result)
    if success{
        print(result)
        let accessToken = result["accessToken"] as? String ?? ""
        self.hitServiceToGetDataFromRunkeeper(accessToken)
    }else{
        print("error...")
    }

    }
 }
```

func hitServiceToGetDataFromRunkeeper(accessToken:String){

```
    showActivityIndicator(true, inViewConroller: self, animated: true)
    let dict = HelperClass.userDefaultForAny("User_Detail")
    var userID = ""
    var serviceKey = ""
    if(dict != nil){
        userID = (dict!["userID"] as? String)!
        serviceKey = (dict!["service_key"] as? String)!
    }

    var paramDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    paramDictionary = ["method":"runkeeperLogin","service_key":serviceKey,"userID":userID,"runkeeperAccessToken":accessToken,"isRunkeeperConnect":"1"]

    print_debug(paramDictionary)

    FSServicesClass.sharedInstance.postWithParamater(paramDictionary, sBlock: { (result) in
        if(NSDictionary(dictionary: result).valueForKey("success")?.integerValue == 1){
            showActivityIndicator(false, inViewConroller: self, animated: true)

            self.btnRunKeeperConnected.setTitle("Connected", forState: .Normal)
            if self.btnFitBitConnected.titleLabel?.text == "Connected"{
                self.btnFitBitConnected.setTitle("Disconnected", forState: .Normal)
            }

            print(result)

            let dict = HelperClass.userDefaultForAny("User_Detail")
            HelperClass.removeFromUserDefaultForKey("User_Detail")

            let dict2 = updateUserDetailForConnetectdAppsAndDevices(dict!, isfitbitConnected: "0", isRunkeeperConnected: "1")

            HelperClass.saveToUserDefault(dict2, key: "User_Detail")
            popAlertMessageController(self, title: "Alert", message: NSDictionary(dictionary: result).valueForKey("errstr") as? String ?? "")

        }else{
            showActivityIndicator(false, inViewConroller: self, animated: true)
            popAlertMessageController(self, title: "Alert", message: NSDictionary(dictionary: result).valueForKey("errstr") as? String ?? "")

        }
        }, fBlock: {(ErrorResult) in
            showActivityIndicator(false, inViewConroller: self, animated: true)
            popAlertMessageController(self, title: "Please try again", message: NSDictionary(dictionary: ErrorResult).valueForKey("errstr")  as? String ?? "")
            //print(ErrorResult)
    })

}
```

Comment: Can you share runkeeper api that you are using?

Comment: Are you using OAuth 1.0 or OAuth 2.0 ?

Comment: using OAuth 2.0

Comment: Are you sure, Your cache/Cookies are clearing every time on click button?

Comment: @iDeveloper : I want to clear cache/cookies, but its not happening

Comment: @Ishika Can you please tell me, How to implement Runkeeper into your app, means to say - By Using Cocoa Pod or Direct implement by code?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete cookies from UIWebView of runkeeper by following way

```
let storage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
for cookie: NSHTTPCookie in storage.cookies! {
        storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
}
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

OR

```
let cookieJar : NSHTTPCookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
    for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! as [NSHTTPCookie]{
        NSLog("cookie.domain = %@", cookie.domain)

        if cookie.domain == "www.Your runkeeper url.com" ||
            cookie.domain == "api.Your runkeeper api .com"{
            cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
```

also remove runkeeper token from user default.

Comment: Its Not Working

Answer (score 0):

Authorize the User
You begin by trying to connect to RunKeeper. If the user previously authorized the app and the access token, is still available, the connection will happen immediately and without any intervention:

```
  [[AppData sharedAppData].runKeeper tryToConnect:self];
```

If the user has not granted authorization OR the access token has been lost/deleted, your delegate method needsAuthentication will be called. In this method, you can request authorization via OAuth.

```
  - (void)needsAuthentication {
    [[AppData sharedAppData].runKeeper tryToAuthorize];
  }
```

For login in purpose it's using OAuth so once the login is successful it will store the token and creds so you need to manually clear the keychain prefrences. For doing that check below:

Removing Accounts

To remove an account and its tokens from the store:

```
[[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore]  removeAccount:account];
```

Note that if you used a UIWebView to request access to a service as described above, it's likely that the token has been cached in `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]`

You can remove the auth token from the cookie cache using:

```
for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
    if([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:@"myapp.com"]) {
        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Where myapp.com is the domain from which you received the auth token -- likley the authorizationURL assigned to the store at the time of request. As a convenience, you may want to store the domain of the token in the account.userData so that it is readily available if you need to delete the cookies.